# Proving if G is a 3-regular graph, then the size of edge cut equals size of min size of vertex cut

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/t-79.5203/luennot/slides5.pdf.pdf on page 10 of 39 is the proof. (This link may no longer be active).

It's theorem 4.1.11, which says "If G is a 3-regular graph, then $\kappa(G) = \kappa'(G)$", where $\kappa(G)$ is the minimum size of a vertex set $S$ s.t. $G-S$ is disconnected or has at least one vertex. $\kappa'(G)$ is the minimum size of edge set $F$ s.t. $G-F$ has more than one component.

What confuses me about the proof is showing why $\kappa'(G) = |S|$, where $S$ = $\kappa(G)$ is the minimum vertex cut. A procedure is provided to tell you what edges to delete. But the proof doesn't explain why the number of edges deleted equals $\kappa(G)$.

Comment: The min-size of vertex cut is also called vertex-connectivity. I assume that with "size of edge cut" a minimal size is meant. This is also called edge-connectivity. It is well known that the edge-connectivity is at least as big as the vertex-connectivity. If the procedure shows, that the edge connectivity is not bigger than the vertex-connectivity, it proves the claim. In other words, the procedure must show : If a deletion of $k$ vertices disconnects the graph, the graph can also be disconnected by deleting $k$ edges.

Comment: Yes. What I'm not sure of is why the procedure in the proof shows that we've deleted $k$ edges.

Comment: That's something different.

Comment: My question asks: But the proof doesn't explain why the number of edges deleted equals κ(G)?

Comment: The link you have provided has been flagged as unsafe by my computer security. I don't believe it leads to an active page any longer.

Answer (score 1):

Let S be vertex cut. G-S gives two components H1, H2. Vertices in S has one edge to vertex in H1, one edge to vertex in H2 and one edge to  vertex in S. Claim is if we take edges from S to H1 they make edge cut. Since a vertex in S has only one edge to H1, we pick exactly one edge for every vertex in S (cut vertex set). Hence κ(G)=κ′(G).

Comment: This proof is not correct. You can create a 3-regular graph with a minimal vertex cut, S, such that some vertices in S have 2 edges going to H1 or H2 and one edge going to H2 or H1, respectively.